# CardView with Image under two layout like Twitter card

Tags: android, android-layout

I search to do a cardview like this :

[https://androidtutorialmagic.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/twitter_card_concept_hd.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwyHq.png)

I try, i try but i don't find the good layout to do this .. 
Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` extends `FrameLayout` so you can layout your views like this:

```
<CardView>
    <ImageView width="match_parent" height="xxxdp" src="background" />
    <LinearLayout orientation="vertical" marginTop="yyydp">
        <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <!-- Settings view, avatar view, check mark view -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView text="Username" />
        <TextView text="@username" />
    </LinearLayout>
</CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks. You've really help me !